# Find misses a match to glob pattern unless the pattern is made more specific

Tags: linux, bash, find

I was using `find` to search for a file on my machine like so:

```
find / -name version-1.0.*
```

and the result was just one file in my home directory, `version-1.0.23`. However, if I ran the following:

```
find / -name version-1.0.1*
```

the result was `/data/somelongpath/version-1.0.19`.

Why would this second result be omitted from the results in the first case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a file that matches the glob in the current directory, and your shell is globbing it. Escape the glob.

```
find / -name 'version-1.0.*'
```

Comment: Extra info for readers: "globbing" refers to the shell expanding wildcards into the full filename or a list of filenames. The shell does this before executing the program.